# Polymorphism doesn't work as it should

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, polymorphism

I have spent hours one finding this bug, now at least I know where is the problem but I have no idea why.

So I have:

```
std::vector< std::vector <Organism* > >world;
```

I have base class `Organism` and child classes `Beetle` and `Ant`.

In base class `Organism` I have virtual functions:

```
    private:
         bool energy;
    public:
    Organism():energy(true){}
    virtual void removeEnergy(){
        energy = false;
    }
    virtual bool hasEnergy(){
        return energy;
    }

    virtual void resetEnergy(){
        energy = true;
    }
```

And I have NOT overwritten them in any of the child classes. I have called base class constructor in child classes.

When I call this function:

```
void World::replaceOrganism(int x, int y, int newX, int newY){  
        world[newX][newY] = world[x][y];
        world[x][y] = new Organism;
        world[newX][newY]->removeEnergy(); // this line
}
```

It removes energy only from this class objects. That means if in vector `world` are multiple Beetles then by this line:

```
world[newX][newY]->removeEnergy();
```

energy is removed from all of them.

I think its something with vectors. Anyone have any suggestions? If you need more info -> comment I will add.

One more thing if I remove that line:

```
world[newX][newY]->removeEnergy();
```

then energy of `Organism` class objects or its children doesn't change.

***EDITED***

Creating world vector:

```
world.resize(worldSizeX);

    for (int x = 0; x < worldSizeX; x++){
        world[x] = std::vector< Organism* >(worldSizeY);

        // INITATES world ARRAY
        for (int y = 0; y < worldSizeY; y++){
            world[x][y] = new Organism;
        }
        // !INITATES world ARRAY
    }
```

***EDITED***

Changing replaceOrganism function with this:

```
void World::replaceOrganism(int x, int y, int newX, int newY){  
        delete world[newX][newY];   
        world[newX][newY] = world[x][y];
        delete world[x][y];
        world[x][y] = new Organism;
 }
```

deletes all class objects that word[newX][newY] is pointing, but function is called only once.

***EDITED***

function that replaces `Organism` class objects with its children.

```
bool World::createOrganism(int x, int y, Organism* organism){
    Organism* empty = new Organism;
    if (world[x][y]->type() != empty->type()){
        delete empty;
        return false;
    }
    else{
        delete empty;
        world[x][y] = organism;
        return true;
    }
}
```

I call it by:

```
createOrganism(2,3,new Beetle);
```

***EDITED***

```
void World::generateOrganisms(Organism* organism, int amount){
    while (amount != 0){
        int x = rand() % worldSizeX;
        int y = rand() % worldSizeY;
        if (createOrganism(x, y, organism)){
            amount--;
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is pointing to the same object.

Comment: This is not clear.  What do you mean by "is removed from all of them".  Please construct a test-case that demonstrates this.

Comment: Are you sure you are initializing the world correctly? As I can guess, this means that every Beetle pointer in your world points to the same  Beetle.

Comment: test case? It looks like I would have called a function that removes energy from all Beetles or all Ants.

Comment: I think you mean "as expected"

Comment: I've read with vectors you dont need to call delete. This is not true?

Comment: @Cirvis Could you please explain what do you expect the RemoveOrganism function to do?

Comment: At the moment it is impossible to state what is wrong, as you've only shown disconnected pieces of code.  Please work to construct a [test case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok. The world seems to be initialized correctly. But I can't see where your problem with polymorphism is.

Comment: A rule of thumb (after 10 years of C++): it is *never* the compiler, polymorphism or the language. These *always* works as they should, the problem is with the code. Believe me.

Comment: @Dadam To be more exact, I can't see where does he use polymorphism (yet).

Comment: I have many beetles and ants in that vector. Could this be caused because I dont delete replaced vector parts?

Comment: @Heron If he didn't, would make my advice off-topic?

Comment: @Heron There isn't any. Not really anyway. OP states he has virtual functions but has not overridden any of them. So they might as well not be virtual at all.

Comment: @Dadam Not at all. That should be a rule of thumb for any using any compiler or interpreter that has been used by a lot of experiences programmers.

Comment: Did you try running this with valgrind to detect illegal memory access?

Comment: @Cirvis You should post the code where your Organisms from world get replaced with Beetles or Ants.

Comment: this wrong (as I assume) behaviour : `energy is removed from all of them.`, would happen if energy were static variable, or if you have had by accident copied the same organism instance pointers all over your vector, it is also possible that you have somme weired undefined bahaviour...

Comment: `energy` isn't static, as stated in the question. I also think that is just the same object pointed to by different pointers.

Comment: @Cirvis we are all guessing. Please make a minimal example and post it here, completely.

Comment: @user1708860 You might be barking at the wrong tree.

Comment: @MarcinJedrzejewski yes I know, but how can you explain if I delete it then everthing in its type in vector is deleted?

Comment: Im starting to think they are all pointing to one Beetle/Ant object.. That would explain a lot

Comment: @Cirvis Although this is off the actual topic of the question, the vector calls the destructor of the objects that are being hold in it. But you are holding pointers to objects, so no, it doesn't call delete by itself.

Comment: @Cirvis That is what we all are thinking. But from the code that you posted, we can't find anything wrong. If you can, it would be great to put into a gist or pastebin all the code of the World and Organism classes.

Comment: @Heron isn't last line a proof of it in the post?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67431/discussion-between-heron-and-cirvis).

Comment: "Everything is pointing to the same object." - :) and thats your answer

Comment: such gratuitous use of `new`/`delete`.

Comment: Can you lose the repeated "EDITED" noise and integrate the bits you added later into the main flow of your question (such as it is)? SO posts are not procedural dramas.

Comment: Stop all this, I've run out of popcorn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `generateOrganisms(Organism* organism, int amount)` all the several pointers you set up refer to the same single organism.  So all the same Beetle.

You need to foresee an additional virtual function for your Organism :

```
Organism *clone()  {
   // create a new organism of the same type 
   }
```

This virtual function should be overwritten for each child, to create a new organism using the correct constructor.

You could then update your creation function:

```
bool World::createOrganism(int x, int y, Organism* organism){
    Organism* empty = new Organism;
    if (world[x][y]->type() != empty->type()){
        delete empty;
        return false;
    }
    else{
        delete empty;
        world[x][y] = organism->clone();  // use a clone, not the original
        return true;
    }
}
```

In addition, I'm not sure that all unused objects are deleted as needed  (at least, difficult to say with only the snipets you provide).  It could be worth investigating the potential use of shared_ptr, to avoid leaking memory.

Comment: So you are saying if I call functions like `myFunction(new Class);`
Then `new Class` object is never deleted?

Comment: Thats it ! `new` creates an object that will remain until you `delete` it. It's different from an anonymous object that get's automatically destroyed at the end of the expression, or from a local object that gets destroyed at the end of the bloc/function in which it was created.

Comment: I just read that it differs from compiler to compiler. And it don't seem to be good practice. And writing in each function `if( string == "Beetle"){
//do stuff
}` doesnt seem good as well. What do you suggest?

Comment: That's the purpose of polymorphism.  Instead of a lot of conditional code depending on the type, you put the stuff to do in a virtual function,  or you write in in such a way that it depends on virtual functions for all the type specific stuff to do.